# Hide Plotly Dash Sunburst Hover label

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, sunburst-diagram

I am unable to hide the label, division and parent from hover tooltips

```
path=[pune,division,taluka,village]
value = df['Project Count'].tolist()
fig_sunburst = px.sunburst(df, path=path, values=value,
                                    color='Division',title="Taluka Wise Project Count")
fig_sunburst.update_traces(hoverinfo = 'ids+value')
```

df is a dataframe with the column ['Pune','division','taluka','village','Project Count']

[image]

When I hover over Khed taluka I get the tooltip as shown above. I want the id to be displayed first then the value. Rest all should be hidden. Also how can I rename value to 'Project Count'

Answer (score 2):

Below you find an example from the plotly website. It should work the same for sunbursts

[image: Scatter Example]

Comment: We can use this for columns present in dataframe. I was able to hide 'division' but not the 'labels' and 'parent' values

Comment: Could you somehow build a reproduceable example? Its hard to tell with no data where "labels" come from

Comment: If you want to rename the "value" to "Project Count" you can simply rename the object you are using for this.

Project_Count = df['Project Count'].tolist()
fig_sunburst = px.sunburst(df, path=path, values=Project_Count,
                                    color='Division',title="Taluka Wise Project Count")